# csv.writer and csv.DictWriter doesn't recognize delimiter for columns

Tags: csv, delimiter

I hope someone can help  me, I have to create and fill up csv files with numerical data, So,first I  started to use the module csv and trying to run examples, but when it creates the file csv and fill the data, this data appears as only one column, i tested many examples what i found on the internet ,even from python sites, but no code worked.

```
with open('names.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Baked', 'last_name': 'Beans'})
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Lovely', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Wonderful', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
```

and another code is :

```
    file = open("outFile.csv", "w", newline="")
csvWriter = csv.writer(file)  # Defaults to the excel dialect
csvWriter.writerow(['item1', 'item2', 'item3', '4', '5', '6'])
csvWriter.writerow(['1stInSecondRow', "2", "22", str(3)])
file.close()
```

Here the picture of csv files
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/981ap4ddgelwb2u/AADxx5ETo4ZbVcY36cSDJ6Sda?dl=0

Thanks in advance for your time, i  hope someone can help.
Note: I use office plus 2016

Comment: The problem is in the *usage* of Excel, not the CSV file. Open the CSV file up with a *text editor* and verify valid CSV is written (ie. "1stInSecondRow,2,22,3" is a valid/expected CSV line from the second example). If using Excel there may need to be an "Import" done (selecting the delimiter is an option during a CSV Import).

Comment: ie. https://www.hesa.ac.uk/support/user-guides/import-csv , https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba , https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/05/01/convert-csv-excel/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :), it helped a lot